# Cannot bind ItemsControl to ObserveableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

As the title states I am having a problem binding an `ObservableCollection` to an `ItemsControl`.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:DeConfigurator.Classes"

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ext:InAppSink.Logs}" Name="LogList">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Expander Header="{Binding Level}">
         <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBlock.Text>
               <Binding Path="FormattedEntry" />
            </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
       </Expander>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

InAppSink:

```
namespace DeConfigurator.Classes
{
    public class InAppSink : ILogEventSink
    {
        static readonly int MAX_ITEMS = 200;
        static readonly int TO_REMOVE = 50;
        
        public ObservableCollection<LogItem> Logs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();

        public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            if (logEvent == null){throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvent)); }            

            if(Logs.Count > MAX_ITEMS)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < TO_REMOVE; ++i)
                {
                    Logs.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            Logs.Add(new LogItem(logEvent));            
        }
    }

    public class LogItem
    {
        readonly ITextFormatter _textFormatter =
            new MessageTemplateTextFormatter(
                "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [{Level}] [{Method}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        );


        public string FormattedEntry { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

        public LogItem(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            var renderSpace = new StringWriter();
            _textFormatter.Format(logEvent, renderSpace);
            FormattedEntry = renderSpace.ToString();

            Level = logEvent.Level.ToString();
            LogDate = logEvent.Timestamp.DateTime;

        }
    }
}
```

The outcome I am after is to have each log entry display as a collapsed expander with the Level and date as the header and the formatted log entry as the text content when dropped. What I get is each character from the text "ext:InAppSink.Logs" is used to create the expander objects. Why is this binding not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind to a property of an object you have to set the `Path` of the Binding to the name of the source property, while the source object is typically passed via the `DataContext` of the target object of the Binding.

For details, see [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0) on Microsoft Docs.

---

So replace

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ext:InAppSink.Logs}"
```

with

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Logs}"
```

and assign an instance of the InAppSink class to the DataContext of the view, e.g. in the MainWindow constructor:

```
private readonly InAppSink sink = new InAppSink();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = sink;
}
```

---

The `Logs` property should also be readonly, like

```
public ObservableCollection<LogItem> Logs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
```

or fire a change notification.

Comment: That's excellent and has worked to a point but I now get an exception: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread. In case you hadn't realised this is also a serilog sink. The error when I try to add a logItem.

Comment: You would have to make sure that Log elements are added from the UI thread. There is nothing in your question that indicates that there is some background processing. Search that specific error message on StackOverflow, you will find solutions.

Comment: Yes it is because I am using it as a sink for logging and therefore creating it outside of ui. I will accept your answer anyway as what I asked for is solved so thanks.

Comment: Seems I had to add
`App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
 {
         Logs.Add(new LogItem(logEvent));
  });
`
to my code

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this. You could also derive InAppSink from DispatcherObject, make sure the instance is created in the main thread, then use its own Dispatcher property. It is the same Dispatcher, but you would not have to access Application.Current.